# iOS Notifications by the system for an audio application in background

Tags: ios, audio, background, notifications, interrupt

I have an audio recording/playing application. It runs in the background. When it goes to the background, and if any other audio application is opened or starts using the audio resources, I want to handle my application appropriately.

iOS provides a way to send such notifications as seen in the ipod player. When it goes into background, and another audio app is opened, the ipod player detects it and stops playing.

How do you detect it? Are there specific notifications/interrupts that will be sent to your background app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to listen any types of notifications, you can configure your **AVAudioSession** to handle all this stuff for you. All you have to do is set appropriate category.
In case of **other** apps, they just set *AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient* so iPod app have to silence itself.